# Why is my TCP connection attempt via PHP acting weird?

Tags: linux, php, tcp, sockets, netcat

<sub>I'm not sure if this is better here or on SO but since the issue isn't in the programming I figured it applies here (or on U&L or on serverfault, but I guess/hope I'm fine on here).</sub>

I want to send TCP commands to an instance of [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) from PHP.

Until now I used: `shell_exec('echo "msg user#idXXXXXX message" | nc 127.0.0.1 9007');` and it worked fine. But there are variables and user input involved and even though I do quote my variables I think this is bad OPSEC, so instead I want to use PHP's 
[sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), but here the issues begin.

The TCP server is started under the user "B" on the server. PHP runs as "www-data". Running the above `shell_exec` works fine, as user `www-data`. Being logged in as user `A` and running the command directly in a bash shell works too. Using bare netcat I can also connect to the socket as user `A`, that's why I think a permission issue isn't the case here. User `A` is a normal user without special permissions.

My PHP code:

```php
$fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 9007, $errno, $errstr, 5);
fwrite($fp, 'msg user#idXXXX "message"');
```

What this does is absolutely nothing.
**And here comes the reason why I consider this not appropriate on StackOverflow:**

If I try to connect to port `9001` (for testing) instead of `9007` (what tg-cli runs on) after running `nc -l 9001` as user `A`, it works perfectly fine and I can see the message PHP should send on the `nc` output.

Judging from this the issue must be somewhere outside of my short PHP code, but I have no clue where to look. **The connection is established** but `fwrite` is not sending anything.

```php
    $fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 9007, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if(!$fp){
        echo "$errstr ($errno)"; die();
    }else{
        echo "test"; // THIS IS BEING PRINTED
        fwrite($fp, 'msg user#idXXXXX "message"');
        while(!feof($fp)){
            echo fgets($fp);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

This is the entire codeblock in question. The `test` is being printed, the `fwrite` is being executed (since PHP enters the while loop) but `tg-cli` receives nothing. The PHP script then is completely stuck in the while-loop (no output!) until I `SIGTERM` apache2.

**Edit:** The output of tg-cli in debug mode when I try to send the message:

```
*** 1538301112.516826 Accepting incoming connection
*** 1538301112.517262 Read from incoming connection
```

**Edit2:** For further permissions testing I ran `sudo -u www-data echo 'dialog_list' | nc 127.0.0.1 9007` - with success.

**Edit3:** I also double-checked with `base64` that PHP's `fwrite` sends exactly what it's supposed to send.

**Edit4:** I can rule out that the issue lays in the response from the server back to PHP as tg-cli reports that it's reading from the TCP connection but it's not processing it. E.g. when i use `shell_exec` or `nc` on the shell it reports that it sent a query to Telegram's datacenter after reading from the TCP stream. This is not the case when using my above PHP code.

**Edit5:** I've also tried to suffix the TCP command with `\n`, `\r` or `\n\r` but again without success. Could it be that I need to end the command with something specific? None of this is needed when using bare `nc` or `shell_exec()` though.

Comment: Is the missing comma after `fwrite($fp` a typo in the question itself or in the original code?

Comment: @grawity It was a typo. Fixed that and another one too.

Comment: does PHP have an fflush and have you tried using it after fwrite?

Comment: @JonasSchäfer It does. I've tried, no change in behaviour. I feel like the issue must lay something else. I sadly can't see the exact message `tg-cli` receives so maybe there's an issue during transport? I really don't know why `nc` would work perfect fine then though.